# How do I filter table only on certain records based off other parameters?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this (alot more columns then listed below):

```
status    type       cid
R         C           1
C         D           2
R         D           3
R         D           4
C         E           2
```

For every cid that has a `status` of `C`, I want only want to keep the row that has `type` equal to `D`. How would i do this?

The new table should look like this:

```
status    type       cid
R         C           1
C         D           2
R         D           3
R         D           4
```

I tried this, but did not work:

```
select * from table where status = 'C' and type <> 'E' group by cid
```

I want to maintain all other records in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=32bf7208b65b41a8e1fc3cdf28211025)

```
WHERE status != 'C' OR (status = 'C' and type = 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.type = 'D'
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where cid = t.cid and status = 'C'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ogq3nJZ3WafjVtsajeXmzJ/0).
Results:

```
| status | type | cid |
| ------ | ---- | --- |
| R      | C    | 1   |
| C      | D    | 2   |
| R      | D    | 3   |
| R      | D    | 4   |
```